# Mongodb shard balancing failed

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Data balancing fails on Mongo cluster with 1 `mongos` and 3 `mongod` instances. All the data for the collection `fs.chunks` stays in the same shard with the following error.

Env: Ubuntu- AWS m3.large,

error from `sh.status()`

> 6 : Failed with error 'could not acquire collection lock for test.fs.chunks to migrate chunk [{ : MinKey },{ : MaxKey }) :: caused by :: Lock for migrating chunk [{ : MinKey }, { : MaxKey }) in test.fs.chunks is taken.', from shard0001 to shard0000
>   3826 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because there are still 7 deletes from previous migration', from shard0000 to shard0001
>   7655 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because there are still 4 deletes from previous migration', from shard0001 to shard0000

Comment: Hi, It is 3.0.4

Answer (score 0):

As I am able to see the chunks error such as

> 3826 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the
>   data transfer: can't accept new chunks because there are still 7
>   deletes from previous migration', from shard0000 to shard0001 7655 :
>   Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data
>   transfer: can't accept new chunks because there are still 4 deletes
>   from previous migration', from shard0001 to shard0000

As `Asya Kamsky` google groups documentation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Rh52ImKYPL4) When importing a large amount of data it is *always* preferable to pre-split the collection and distribute chunks evenly across the shards and disable balancer  *before* starting the data load.   Otherwise you will see the migrations and new data load compete for the same resources, reducing the performance of both.

Yes, you should/can re-enable the balancer after the import is done.   But of course it's better to presplit/pre-balance as described  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/).

For further your ref [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14047)

Answer (score 0):

Originally a comment by [jjussi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/121114/jjussi):

> I have seen those error myself, years ago.
>
> If I remember rightly, a restart of the source shard's primary was
>   enough to flush those stuck deletes.